# Integrate FullCalendar 2.6.1 in Angularjs 2.0

Tags: jquery, angular, fullcalendar

I am trying to integrate FullCalendar in an Angularjs 2 application. I did search for an example where some have done it already, but could not find any examples for Angularjs 2. Can some one point me in the right direction.
I am getting following error when the application loads up.

```
TypeError: b.class is not a constructor
at Pa.Calendar.ra.extend.instantiateView (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js?1459824069953:8:28997)
```

Following is my controller code.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
date:Date = new Date();
ngAfterContentInit() {
    var calendarDiv: any = $('#calendar');
    calendarDiv.fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
        events: [
        ],
        resources: [
        ]
        // other options go here...
    });
}
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('On init ! ');
    $('#calendar').text('Hi I am replace');
}
```

Template code:

```
<div id='calendar'>Test calendar</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Tried Google. No luck.

Comment: primeNG has a component already made with fullcalendar

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out what was wrong. I was using the incompatible version of jquery, fullcalendar and fullcalendar-scheduler. Used the FullCalendar demo(from the official website) to figure out the versions required.